# Переменные в блоках

Tags: c, c++

Вот есть такая последовательность объявлений переменных внутри функции

```
{
    void *out = NULL;

    // ... 
    {
        void *in = NULL;

        // ... 
    }
}
```

Когда память под переменные out и in размещается на стеке: когда управление входит внутрь функции или когда управление входит внутрь блока, отделенного фигурными скобками? Происходят ли какие-либо изменения со стеком и размещаемыми переменными при пересечении блока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от компилятора и целевой платформы. По идее, компилятор всегда может вычислить максимальную глубину и выделить всё что нужно в стеке заране (в эпилоге функции, т.е. при входе). С другой стороны, он может действительно увеличивать\уменьшать размер стека при переходе внутрь вложенного блока. 
Разумеется, переменные из вложенного блока будут вам недоступне из внешнего контекста.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрим на примере и сделаем переменные volatile, чтобы исключить оптимизации.

```
int main()
{
    volatile char out = 1;

    {
        volatile char in = -1;

        out += in;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Собираем и дисассемблируем (gcc, objdump):

```
8048394:    55                      push   %ebp
8048395:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048397:    83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
804839a:    c6 45 ff 01             movb   $0x1,-0x1(%ebp)
804839e:    c6 45 fe ff             movb   $0xff,-0x2(%ebp)
80483a2:    0f b6 45 ff             movzbl -0x1(%ebp),%eax
80483a6:    89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
80483a8:    0f b6 45 fe             movzbl -0x2(%ebp),%eax
80483ac:    8d 04 02                lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%eax
80483af:    88 45 ff                mov    %al,-0x1(%ebp)
80483b2:    0f b6 45 ff             movzbl -0x1(%ebp),%eax
80483b6:    0f be c0                movsbl %al,%eax
80483b9:    c9                      leave  
80483ba:    c3                      ret
```

Если я не ошибаюсь, операции со стеком проводятся при входе в функции, а потом он уже используется либо не используется.

Answer (score 1):

Память под переменную на стеке выделяется в момент входа в блок фигурных скобок. Соответственно, при выходе за фигурные скобки все локальные для этого блока переменные убиваются. Хотя Вы к ним за пределами блока обратиться не сможете. Единственный нюанс - конструкции вида

```
for (int i=0;...) {...}
```

которые, в зависимости от компилятора и/или его опций могут разворачиваться в

```
int i;
for (i=0;...)
{...}
// здесь мы можем с i вытворять дальнейшие упражнения :-)
```

или

```
...
for (int i=0; ...)
{...}
// здесь i уже неопределена, т.к. локальна для блока {...} под for
```

Также я считаю, что размазывать создание переменных по блокам не очень рационально. Минус такой: легко можно создать две одинаковые разные переменные и запутаться между ними.

```
...
int i;
...
{
    int i;
    ...
    i = 10; // меняем значение "внутренней" i
    ::i = 10; // меняем значение i из внешнего блока, но при этом если уровней вложенности несколько, то доступ к локальным i из промежуточных блоков, если они там, конечно, есть, теряется.
}
```

Заодно исчезает наглядность описания переменных, которая есть в паскале (блок определений var).
Разумно локально создавать объекты, которые должны быть автоматически уничтожены. Это удобно при использовании "умных указателей", которые автоматически убивают объект, на который указывают. И нет головной боли - освободили мы память или нет. При этом удобно, что объект живет строго там, где он нужен. Где он не нужен - к нему просто не обратиться.

Comment: Просто как комментарий - в некоторых источниках (Страуструп??? не уверен) рекомендуют в программах на C++ переменные объявлять там, где они впервые нужны. Это способствует более эффективному распределению памяти компилятором... Кроме того, не забудешь удалить лишнюю переменную если вдруг после изменения кода она уже не нужна... (Хотя, конечно, Visual Studio генерирует warning'и на неиспользуемые переменные)...

Answer (score 0):

В gcc (MinGW) и с оптимизацией и без нее стек как для локальных переменных, так и для параметров вызываемых функций устанавливается при входе в функцию и до ее окончания не изменяется.